# Erro no BindValue (ou no INSERT)

Tags: pdo

**Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\all_processo.php on line 92**

Linha do erro:

```html
  $conexao->beginTransaction();
 

   try{
 

  $sql = "INSERT INTO processos (proc_id, numero, assunto, requerente, status)
   VALUES(:proc_id, :numero, :assunto, :requerente, :status)";
  $sql = "INSERT INTO informes (inf_id, de_setor, para_setor, informe, data, informante, processo_id)
   VALUES (:inf_id, :de_setor, :para_setor, :informe, :data, :informante, :processo_id)";



   $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
   $stm->bindValue(':proc_id', $proc_id);
   $stm->bindValue(':numero', $numero);   
   $stm->bindValue(':assunto', $assunto);
   $stm->bindValue(':requerente', $requerente);
   $stm->bindValue(':status', $status);
   $stm->bindValue(':inf_id', $inf_id);
   $stm->bindValue(':de_setor', $de_setor);
   $stm->bindValue(':para_setor', $para_setor);
   $stm->bindValue(':informe', $informe);
   $stm->bindValue(':data', $data);
   $stm->bindValue(':informante', $informante);
   $stm->bindValue(':processo_id', $processo_id);
   $retorno = $stm->execute();               //LINHA 92

   if ($retorno):
    echo "<div class='center1' role='alert'>Processo inserido com sucesso, aguarde você está sendo redirecionado...</div> ";
    echo "<div class='loader'</div>";
      else:
       echo "<div class='center1' role='alert'>Erro ao inserir processo, aguarde!</div>";
    echo "<div class='loader'</div>";
   endif;

   echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='4;URL=listarprocessos.php'>";
   
     $conexao->commit();
  
   }
   catch(Exception $e){

    echo $e->getMessage();

    $conexao->rollBack();
}
```

Comment: Estás a declarar duas vezes a var `$sql`, sendo que a segunda é a que vai prevalecer, e não tem o mesmo número de `VALUES` que os teus `bindValue`

Comment: pra isso fiz a transação.

devo colocar $sql e $sql2? (por exemplo)

Comment: Não, no segundo `$sql` você faz `$sql .= "INSERT`...

Comment: e tiro a transação? obrigado desde já.

Comment: vc precisa fazer dois inserts separados e os repectivos binds.

Comment: fiz da seguinte forma:  

 $sql = "INSERT INTO processos(proc_id, numero, assunto, requerente, status)
   VALUES(:proc_id, :numero, :assunto, :requerente, :status)";


   $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql.="INSERT INTO informes(inf_id, de_setor, para_setor, informe, data, informante, processo_id)
   VALUES (:inf_id, :de_setor, :para_setor, :informe, :data, :informante, :processo_id)");

porém não resolveu o problema.

Comment: vc tem fazer algo como `$processos = 'insert .... values (:id, :nome)';$stm->prepare($processos); if($stm->execute()){ $informes = 'insert .... values (:outroId, outroNome)'; $stm->preapre($informes) ....`. Veja que agora tem duas variáveis de insert, duas chamadas de `prepare()` e `execute()` só não esqueça de fazer os binds antes do execute.

Comment: depois de feito o que tu falou, @rray, tá registrando duas vezes o mesmo dado.

Comment: Acredito que seja melhor criar uma nova pergunta já o código mudou e o erro também.

Comment: ok, porém não tem erro visível